# Geoprocessor: using arc toolbox in vb.net

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

i am doing the following in order to use the predefined tool points to line in arctool box

```
        Dim ptoline As ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.PointsToLine = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.PointsToLine
        Dim pgeo As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor
        ptoline.Input_Features = " D:\Mayur\shapefiles\new_pooint_3.shp"
        ptoline.Output_Feature_Class = " D:\Mayur\shapefiles\new_line123.shp"

        pgeo.OverwriteOutput = True

        Dim geoProcessorResult As IGeoProcessorResult
        geoProcessorResult = pgeo.Execute(ptoline, Nothing)
```

i dont know the exact syntax of it. after running it shows error on

```
geoProcessorResult = pgeo.Execute(ptoline, Nothing)
```

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

the references geoprocessor and datamanagement tools are included.

the path to the input feature is correct.
the o/p file is created automatically.

Is there any prerequisite to run geoprocessor?

Do I have to do that workspace thing also ?

---

[image: snapshot of my arc toolbox]

now i know that this "points to line " is something different from other tools.
it is a (third party tool) CUSTOM TOOL i guess and their interfacing is different,

i tried out with other tools and they all worked perfectly.

Can you tell me whether my conclusion that it is a custom tool is correct or not?

How do I interface these custom tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
Dim pgeo As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor

pgeo.AddToolbox("c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Data Management Tools.tbx")

Dim parameters As IVariantArray = New VarArray 

parameters.Add("D:\Mayur\shapefiles\new_pooint_3.shp")

parameters.Add("D:\Mayur\shapefiles\new_line123.shp")

pgeo.Execute("PointsToLine", parameters, Nothing)
```